# Catalyst 3750 Series Port Usage

Tags: cisco, ip

I am looking for an easier way to determine what server is using what Port on our Cisco 3750 Core Switch. I can trace the Cat5 but was hoping that the switch could tell me what IP was in usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although 3750's are L3-switches and you can find that information using a combination of 'show mac address-table' and 'show arp' I'd suggest you make life much easier for yourself by simply naming ports in the config - this is what everyone I've ever come across does.

Comment: gah.. just beat me to it. :)

Comment: just what I was looking for. Requires work on my end, but it is perfect. I inherited this network and trying to clean up. Thanks so much for your assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

We deployed a network inventory program on our servers named **Netdisco**.
If it can learn the MAC <-> IP mappings from a router it can exactly do what you need.

We use it on our linux based network management server machine.